# If $x_2(t)/x_1(t)=y_2(t)/y_1(t)$, then is $\vec Y(t)=(y_1(t),y_2(t))$ a reparametrization of $\vec X(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

The definition of a parametrized curve $\vec X:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ was given by a continuous function $g:J\rightarrow I$, then $\vec \xi =\vec X \circ g:J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a reparametrization of $\vec X(t)$.

However, if $x_2(t)/x_1(t)=y_2(t)/y_1(t)$, then is $\vec Y(t)=(y_1(t),y_2(t))$ a reparametrization of $\vec X(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$?

Comment: Of course not. Take  $(t,t^2)$ and $(t^2,t^3)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I started to realize what went wrong. But are $\vec X$ and $\vec Y$ completely random?

Comment: Completely, no. But if you think about my example, you can come up with infinitely many different examples of your own. When you reparametrize you don’t expect the same independent variable $t$, for starters. There is no extrinsic test such as you’re trying.